# Deploying a smart contract using Hardhat WITHOUT script

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

Literally everywhere I look (other stackoverflow posts, or official docs), the way to deploy a smart contract is always using a script

`npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network ropsten`

I am looking for a way to deploy it only using the npm library "hardhat" without actually running a "script" in terminal.

Does anyone know how?

Comment: I don't know if that's possible using an npm library, if you want to do something like that try with remix, but why you don't wan to run an script to make a deploy?

Comment: @jhonny I am making a software that deploys smart contract with push of a button. And that user will not be able to run a script. I will have to do that. for them programatically in the backend

Comment: Given your use case I think you can make a general use function that deploys the an smart contract, that receive the name of the contract and parameters to pass to the constructor and at the end return the address of the deployed contract, but I'm not sure of how to set the network this way

Comment: I am on the hunt for the same functionality! Curious it is not so simple.

Answer (score 0):

So, what I did was put `defaultNetwork: "network name"` in the `module.exports` object inside of your `hardhat.config.js` file.